# Is there really only 1 public transport connection a day between Ljubljana and Kranjska Gora?

Tags: public-transport, slovenia, timetables

I'm trying to get from Ljubljana to Kranjska Gora, from where I want to take a bus to Vršič pass and hike through the Triglav National park. My question is about the first part of the journey.

Using [Nomago.si](https://www.nomago.si/avtobusne-vozovnice/vozni-red?dest_from_name=Ljubljana+Tivolska&dest_from=134&dest_to_name=Kranjska+Gora&dest_to=292&bus_date_from=04.07.2022) I can only find 1 bus going each day:

[image]

[Google maps](https://goo.gl/maps/45xCWStqMNnvEpL89) shows more options, but at the same time displays a warning:

> We don't have the most recent timetables for this area.

So I'm not sure if I can trust their advice.

Is there really only 1 connection a day? If not, where can I find a more elaborate (Slovenian) travel planner that shows the other options as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this local site](https://www.ap-ljubljana.si/en/timetable/?departure=LJUBLJANA+BUS+STATION&destination=Kranjska+Gora), buses leave approximately hourly throughout the day (as indeed you would expect); a one-way adult ticket costs €8.70.

Bizarrely, some foreign sites (for instance, [this one](https://www.omio.co.uk/coaches/ljubljana/kranjska-gora-ejlen)) quote prices of up to £66 for what appears to be the same journey, but by coach instead of bus.